# open file in specified window in emacs

Tags: emacs, dired

How to specify a window in emacs to be used to open new file/buffer for?

When I'm opening a file, say in dired using `o` command, it is opened in a new window. But I want this file to be opened in a window exactly I've specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defun dired-window () (window-at (frame-width) 1))

(eval-after-load 'dired
  '(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "o")
     (lambda ()
       (interactive)
       (let ((dired-window (dired-window)))
         (set-window-buffer dired-window
                            (find-file-noselect 
                             (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
         (select-window dired-window)))))
```

Comment: That doesn't look fail-safe? Wouldn't `dired-window` need to be a function which re-calculated the window to use in the event that the original one no longer existed?

Comment: @phil: Good point.  I edited the answer to make it a function.